# I need Parse Android App migration for cloud code and push but not able to understand where to start for cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I completed local parse server and mongodb installation and app is connected through db and working now, but push and cloud code is not working. I do not have any idea where to put the main.js file in my mac. not getting the cloud folder.

please can somebody guide me .

Comment: I tried npm init, npm install express ,npm install parse server but inside the parse-server directory there is no cloud folder, Can somebody tell me where i did the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to manually create the folder you want to put your Cloud Code in. The easy way is to crate one in your project's root folder and then update the config you pass to Parse Server to point to that directory.

You can find a basic example with a config that includes the Cloud Code folder in the [README](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#parse-server--express) of the Parse Server GitHub repo as well.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to call the cloud code from my app, now can you just give me where to add mandrill api, because i am facing error  can not found module mandrill in my cloud code , I install in the root folder but didn't work.